# Expansion of conditional probability and expected value

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, decimal-expansion

The question-Suppose X and Y are discrete random variables. Match up the follow- ing.

$$(a) E(X^2Y |Y = 2)$$
$$Answer- 2E(X^2|Y = 2)$$

My approach was to expand which I got
$$ 2E(XY |Y=2))$$

I don’t know how to go forward with this- can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see how you got what you got. From an informal point of view it should. be clear that given $Y=2$ then you can pull it out. The rule you can find here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation

Comment: $$\mathbb E[X^2Y\mid Y=2]:=\left.\mathbb E[X^2Y\mid Y]\right|_{Y=2}\underset{(*)}{=}\left.Y\mathbb E[X^2\mid Y]\right|_{Y=2}=2\mathbb E[X^2\mid Y=2],$$ where $(*)$ follow from the fact that if $Z$ is $\mathcal G-$measurable, then $\mathbb E[ZU\mid \mathcal G]=Z\,\mathbb E[U\mid \mathcal G]$ for all $U$ integrable.